# Deploy Image to Amazon ECS service

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, github, amazon-ecs

I am using Github actions to build and deploy docker images to Amazon ECS.

This is the code I used when the action runs:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Build and push Docker images
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v1
        with:
          username: ***
          password: ***
          registry: ***
          repository: ***
          tags: ***
          tag_with_ref: true

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ***
          aws-secret-access-key: ***
          aws-region: ***

      - name: Render Amazon ECS task definition
        id: render-api-container
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
        with:
          task-definition: ***
          container-name: ***
          image: docker.pkg.github.com/company/repo/image:***

      - name: Deploy to Amazon ECS service
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
        with:
          task-definition: ${{ steps.render-api-container.outputs.task-definition }}
          service: ***
          cluster: ***
```

The job runs without errors, but I get this error from Amazon task starts:
[image: ECS Error]

The image was built and deployed to our organization's GitHub packages.

I checked "Auto-assign Public IP" and it is enabled.

The last successful task that was run on Amazon was on February 8.

Comment: the ECS closeter is in VPC, right ? Did you enable DNS resolution in VPC ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html

Comment: Which ECS Launch type are you using ? EC2 or Fargate?  If you are using Amazon Provided DNS and not the custom one, just ensure that the Security Group on the VPC has been allowed port 443 (HTTPS ) as outbound connection.

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan DNS resolution is enabled

Comment: @aashitvyas Fargate, and for security group ports 80 and 443 are allowed as inbound rule and  all traffic from all ports are allowed as outbound rule

Comment: Without looking at how your ECS and VPC setup, it would be hard to answer the question. Is there any way you can provide more information in regards to your current architecture.

Comment: I pushed the image to the Amazon ECR repository and use it instead of the GitHub image. This made the deployment works but it does not answer my question or fix my problem. The problem seemed to be between GitHub packages and Amazon while pulling images.